# Datatable edit do Primefaces não envia valor atualizado para edição

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable

Estou tentando realizar um update através do datatable edit do primefaces, porém não envia o valor do inputtext atualizado para o bean. O processo ocorre quase que corretamente, o valor é enviado e atualizado, porém o valor antigo, já carregado na datatable.

alguém pode me ajudar nessa

**listaProduto.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<ui:composition template= "template.xhtml">

<ui:define name="conteudo" >

<h:form id="form">

            <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true"/>

   <p:dataTable  var="prod" value="#{pBean.listaproduto}" editable="true"  style="margin-bottom:20px" id="listaproduto1" >


    <p:ajax event="rowEditInit" listener="#{pBean.onRowEdit}"    update=":form:msgs" immediate="true"  />
   <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{pBean.onRowCancel}" update=":form:msgs" /> 

   <p:column headerText="Id">

           <h:outputText value="#{prod.id}"/>

   </p:column>
   <p:column headerText="Nome">
       <p:cellEditor>
           <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{prod.nome}"/></f:facet>
           <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText  value="#{prod.nome}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
       </p:cellEditor>
   </p:column>
   <p:column headerText="Preço">
       <p:cellEditor>
           <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{prod.preco}"/></f:facet>
           <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText  value="#{prod.preco}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
       </p:cellEditor>
   </p:column>
   <p:column headerText="Fornecedor">
       <p:cellEditor>
           <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{prod.fornecedor}"/>     </f:facet>
           <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText  value="#{prod.fornecedor}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
       </p:cellEditor>
   </p:column>
   <p:column headerText="Categoria">
       <p:cellEditor>
           <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{prod.categoria}"/></f:facet>
           <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="cate"  value="#{prod.categoria}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
       </p:cellEditor>
   </p:column>             



 <p:column style="width:32px">
       <p:rowEditor  />


   </p:column> 
</p:dataTable>

        </h:form>



</ui:define>

</ui:composition>

</html>
```

**ProdutoBean**

```
package manager;




import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import org.primefaces.event.RowEditEvent;
import br.com.estoque.model.Produto;
import br.com.estoque.persistence.ProdutoDao;

@ManagedBean(name="pBean")
@ViewScoped
    public class ProdutoBean {
    private Produto produto;
    private List<Produto> listaproduto;

    public ProdutoBean() {
        produto = new Produto();
    }
    public Produto getProduto() {

    return produto;


  }
    public void setProduto(Produto produto) {
      this.produto = produto;
    }


public List<Produto> getListaproduto() {
    try{

        listaproduto = new ProdutoDao().listar();



    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return listaproduto;
}
public void setListaproduto(List<Produto> listaproduto) {
    this.listaproduto = listaproduto;
}

public String cadastrar() {
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        try{

            new ProdutoDao().cadastrar(produto);

            fc.addMessage("formproduto", new FacesMessage(produto.getNome() + "produto cadastrado com sucesso"));

            produto = new Produto();

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            fc.addMessage("formproduto", new FacesMessage(produto.getNome() + "Não cadastrado"));
        }

        return null;        

}


 public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
     System.out.println(produto);
    /* Aqui tudo retorna nulo */

     produto = ((Produto) event.getObject());

        System.out.println(produto);
    /* Aqui retornam os valores iniciais do datatable */   
 }



    public void onRowCancel(RowEditEvent event) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Edit Cancelled");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }

  }
```

Comment: Não entendi o final da sua pergunta, o valor é ou não atualizado ?

Comment: O valor atualizado não é passado para o bean. 
o /*  produto = ((Produto) event.getObject()); */ pega o valor inicial do datatable, e não o valor do input que eu altero.

Comment: Você pode marcar a resposta que melhor lhe ajudou como aceita, clicando no `v` a esquerda, logo abaixo do contador de votos.

Comment: Ah sim, obrigado, sou novo aqui...rs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu nunca editei dessa forma, mas reparei q em seus códigos seu update está atualizando apenas a mensagem. Pode ser que seja isso.
tente assim:

```
<p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{pBean.onRowCancel}" process=":form:listaproduto1" update=":form:msgs :form:listaproduto1" />
<p:ajax event="rowEditInit" listener="#{pBean.onRowEdit}" process=":form:listaproduto1"    update=":form:msgs :form:listaproduto1" immediate="true"  />
```

Só adicionei o i Id da tabela, mas vc pode por apenas ":form:", pelo menos pra testar.

Comment: Tentei destas formas... não funcionou amigo... isso tá quebrando minha cabeça....rs

Comment: Dê uma olhada nas opções de desenvolvedor do navegador, na aba network, e monitore a resposta do ajax., veja se está tudo certo, há, e tente por o "process" tbm. definindo o que vc quer processar. vou atualizar minha resposta com isso.

Comment: Cara, acho que minha questão agora não é mais a parte do ajax... com a verificação do que o estava sendo passado, vi que o valor está sendo passado e atualizado... não sei o pq, mas o hibernate faz muitos selects e  acaba sobrescrevendo a atualização... fique perdidinho de novo...rs

Comment: ainda não sei usar o stackoverflow direito... minha resposta foi lá pra cima...rs

Comment: Ótimo, :-), essas mancadas acontecem, e issso bom, pra os deixar atentos.

Answer (score 1):

consegui resolver. na verdade o problema estava no meu get listaprodutos... após inserir um if e else, testando se lista produto era nulo, funcionou normalmente.
O legal é, como o amigo indicou, verificar sempre os valores passados pelo network do navegador.

Abraços

Answer (score 0):

@Nadinael Silva Teixeira
Obrigado pela ajuda, postando aqui um pedaço do código e o que retorna... agradeço muito a ajuda

pBean

```
         public List<Produto> getListaproduto() {
            try{

            System.out.println( "get " + listaproduto);

                listaproduto = new ProdutoDao().listar();



            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return listaproduto;
        }
```

ProdutoDao

```
        public List<Produto> listar()throws Exception {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        query = session.createQuery("select p from Produto p");

        List<Produto> lista = query.list();
        session.close();

            return lista;
        }
```

Retorno do Console ao clicar no v do rowEditor (repare que antes do 4º select de baixo pra cima, o System.out.println( "get " + listaproduto), retorna o valor correto que passei, produto de id=2, categoria=258)

```
                    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            produto0_.id as id1_0_,
            produto0_.categoria as categori2_0_,
            produto0_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_,
            produto0_.nome as nome4_0_,
            produto0_.preco as preco5_0_ 
        from
            Produto produto0_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            produto0_.id as id1_0_,
            produto0_.categoria as categori2_0_,
            produto0_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_,
            produto0_.nome as nome4_0_,
            produto0_.preco as preco5_0_ 
        from
            Produto produto0_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            produto0_.id as id1_0_,
            produto0_.categoria as categori2_0_,
            produto0_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_,
            produto0_.nome as nome4_0_,
            produto0_.preco as preco5_0_ 
        from
            Produto produto0_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            produto0_.id as id1_0_,
            produto0_.categoria as categori2_0_,
            produto0_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_,
            produto0_.nome as nome4_0_,
            produto0_.preco as preco5_0_ 
        from
            Produto produto0_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            produto0_.id as id1_0_,
            produto0_.categoria as categori2_0_,
            produto0_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_,
            produto0_.nome as nome4_0_,
            produto0_.preco as preco5_0_ 
        from
            Produto produto0_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            produto0_.id as id1_0_,
            produto0_.categoria as categori2_0_,
            produto0_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_,
            produto0_.nome as nome4_0_,
            produto0_.preco as preco5_0_ 
        from
            Produto produto0_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            produto0_.id as id1_0_,
            produto0_.categoria as categori2_0_,
            produto0_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_,
            produto0_.nome as nome4_0_,
            produto0_.preco as preco5_0_ 
        from
            Produto produto0_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            produto0_.id as id1_0_,
            produto0_.categoria as categori2_0_,
            produto0_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_,
            produto0_.nome as nome4_0_,
            produto0_.preco as preco5_0_ 
        from
            Produto produto0_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            produto0_.id as id1_0_,
            produto0_.categoria as categori2_0_,
            produto0_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_,
            produto0_.nome as nome4_0_,
            produto0_.preco as preco5_0_ 
        from
            Produto produto0_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            produto0_.id as id1_0_,
            produto0_.categoria as categori2_0_,
            produto0_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_,
            produto0_.nome as nome4_0_,
            produto0_.preco as preco5_0_ 
        from
            Produto produto0_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            produto0_.id as id1_0_,
            produto0_.categoria as categori2_0_,
            produto0_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_,
            produto0_.nome as nome4_0_,
            produto0_.preco as preco5_0_ 
        from
            Produto produto0_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            produto0_.id as id1_0_,
            produto0_.categoria as categori2_0_,
            produto0_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_,
            produto0_.nome as nome4_0_,
            produto0_.preco as preco5_0_ 
        from
            Produto produto0_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            produto0_.id as id1_0_,
            produto0_.categoria as categori2_0_,
            produto0_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_,
            produto0_.nome as nome4_0_,
            produto0_.preco as preco5_0_ 
        from
            Produto produto0_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 258]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            produto0_.id as id1_0_,
            produto0_.categoria as categori2_0_,
            produto0_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_,
            produto0_.nome as nome4_0_,
            produto0_.preco as preco5_0_ 
        from
            Produto produto0_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            produto0_.id as id1_0_,
            produto0_.categoria as categori2_0_,
            produto0_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_,
            produto0_.nome as nome4_0_,
            produto0_.preco as preco5_0_ 
        from
            Produto produto0_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            produto0_.id as id1_0_,
            produto0_.categoria as categori2_0_,
            produto0_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_,
            produto0_.nome as nome4_0_,
            produto0_.preco as preco5_0_ 
        from
            Produto produto0_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            produto0_.id as id1_0_,
            produto0_.categoria as categori2_0_,
            produto0_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_,
            produto0_.nome as nome4_0_,
            produto0_.preco as preco5_0_ 
        from
            Produto produto0_
```